# opendds TAO_IDL_GEN, OpenDDS_XML_QOS_XSC_Generation, and other skipped packages

Tags: package, opendds

I'm building OpenDDS 3.8 from source.
When running the `configure` command I obtain some skipping messages. Most of them are java (I don't use it so it's ok for me to skip them) but some other messages take my attention:

> Skipping TAO_IDL_GEN (tao_idl_fe.mpc); it requires tao_idl_fe_gen
>
> Skipping  OpenDDS_XML_QOS_XSC_Generation (qos_xml_handler.mpc); it requires xsc.
>
> Skipping OpenDDS_QOS_XML_XSC_Handler (qos_xml_handler.mpc); it requires xerces.
>
> Skipping OpenDDS_CorbaSeq (CorbaSeq.mpc); it avoids no_opendds_safety_profile.
>
> Skipping OpenDDS_Corba (OpenDDS_Corba.mpc); it avoids no_opendds_safety_profile.

I did't found anything regarding these packages. I'd like to know what they do and if I need them (and eventually how to build them).

Answer (score 2):

These are just warnings, the features they need are not enabled so those libraries are not compiled. These are safe to ignore unless you need the QoS XML support or the safety profile

Answer (score 1):

Export path of JAVA, Wireshark, Glib and qt into your bashrc then try to run "./configure --java --wireshark --glib --qt" this is working but giving me error in later state.

Comment: i can configure this successfully but getting error in make